# Задача о числах

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте,решаю задачу и никак не могу ее решить.Пробовал решить следующим методом,от 1 до 300 нашел простые числа,затем по фор-ле включений исключений нашел от 1 до k на правом отрезке,затем на левом,потом от правой части отнял левую.Но проблема в том,что это долго работает.Вот сама задача,если есть идеи выскажите свои соображения.
http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1940

```
#include<iostream>

#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

int a,r,k,prav,lev,answer;
double z;
int ii,jj;
bool f;
cin>>a>>r>>k;
r=a+r;
a=a+1;
vector<int> p;
p.push_back(2);
for(ii=3;ii<=k+1;ii++)
{
    f=true;
    z=ii;
    for(jj=2;jj<=sqrt(z)+1&&f;jj++)
    {
        if(ii%jj==0)
            f=false;
    }
    if(f)
        p.push_back(ii);
}
int sum = 0;
for (int msk=1; msk<(1<<p.size()); ++msk) {
    int mult = 1,
        bits = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<(int)p.size(); ++i)
        if (msk & (1<<i)) {
            ++bits;
            mult *= p[i];
        }

    int cur = r / mult;
    if (bits % 2 == 1)
        sum += cur;
    else
        sum -= cur;
}
prav=r-sum;
 sum = 0;
for (int msk=1; msk<(1<<p.size()); ++msk) {
    int mult = 1,
        bits = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<(int)p.size(); ++i)
        if (msk & (1<<i)) {
            ++bits;
            mult *= p[i];
        }

    int cur = a / mult;
    if (bits % 2 == 1)
        sum += cur;
    else
        sum -= cur;
}
lev=a-sum;
answer=prav-lev;
f=true;
z=a;
for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(z)+1&&f;i++)
{
    if(a%i==0)
        f=false;
}
if(f)
    answer++;
cout<<answer<<endl;
system("pause");`
```

Comment: @ivan145 отформатируйте код и сформулируйте саму задачу (по вашей ссылке ничего нет)

Comment: Все,изменил,теперь все оформлено верно

Comment: Что за левые-правые отрезки?

Answer (score 1):

Лениво разбираться. Посмотрите

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int count(int a, int b, vector<int> v) {
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int y = a; y++ < b;) { // y <- [a+1..b]
        cnt++;
        for(vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
            if(y % *it == 0) {
                cnt--;
                break;
            }
    }
    return cnt;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    int A, B, k, prod = 1, prod1 = 1;
    cin >> A >> B >> k;
    int *sieve = new int[k];
    for(int i=0; i < k; i++) sieve[i] = i + 2;
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < k && sieve[i]*sieve[i] <= (k+1); i++) {
        int n;
        if(n = sieve[i]) {
            int w = n + n;
            cnt++;
            while(w <= k+1) {
                sieve[w - 2] = 0;
                w += n;
            }
        }
    }
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=0; i < k; i++)
        if(sieve[i]) {
            v.push_back(sieve[i]);
            prod *= sieve[i];
            prod1 *= sieve[i] - 1;
        };
    delete [] sieve;
    int a1 = (A + prod - 2) / prod * prod + 1;
    if(a1 < A) a1 += prod;
    int b1 = ((A + B)/ prod) * prod;
    if (b1 > a1) {
        cnt = ((b1 - a1 + 1) / prod) * prod1;
        if(a1 - 1> A) cnt += count(A, a1-1, v);
        if(b1 < A+B) cnt += count (b1, A+B, v);
    } else cnt = count(A, A+B, v);
    cout << cnt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD**

Убрал дурное извлечение квадратного корня. Чего-то с++ на мозги давит нехорошим образом.

**UPD**

Были и ошибки в логике (а, возможно, и остались). Но теперь не проверяю каждое число в интервале (A, B], a вырезаю отрезок из середины (p*n1, p*n2], где p -- произведение k простых чисел. Для каждого отрезка (1, p] + p * i принимаю количество условных чисел равным произведению этих простых чисел минус 1. Доказывать (по индукции) лениво, но вроде так. Ну и начальный и конечный отрезки проверяю некратность этим простым.

Comment: Можете вкратце рассказать в чем заключается ваша идея алгоритма

Comment: @ivan145 Да всё в лоб. Сначала найти простые числа от 2 до k (решето Эратосфена), потом проверить делимость чисел от A+1 до A+B на эти числа. Если не делятся -- простое по версии капитана.

Comment: К сожалению,по версии капитана не проходит,нужно что-то нестандартное,иначе TLE

Comment: Поправил ещё раз. Благодаря @Михаил М

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, надо проверить все числа от А до A+B на делимость на простые числа от 2 до k. Это ну не так уж много операций, учитывая, что большинство чисел делится на 2 или 3.

Хотя в секунду может и не уложиться, поэтому можно взять массив размером... насколько памяти хватит, но по крайней мере в несколько раз меньше, чем B (иначе время его построения будет сопоставимо с временем простой проверки). Точный размер массива должен быть произведением первых простых чисел, допустим, 2*3*5*7. В этом массиве надо вычеркнуть все числа, делящиеся на выбранные простые числа, в случае 2, 3, 5, 7 (с - - вычеркнутые):

1, 2-, 3-, 4-, 5-, 6-, 7-, 8-, 9-, 10-, 11, 12-, 13, 14-, 15-, 16-, 17, 18-, 19, 20-, 21-, 22-, 23, 24-, 25-, 26-, 27-, 28-, 29, 30-, 31, ...

Потом надо составить второй массив, в котором будут перечислены расстояния между оставшимися числами (1, 10, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, ...). Таким образом получим относительно небольшое количество чисел, означающих, через сколько заведомо не простых чисел при проверке A - A+B надо перепрыгивать. Оставшиеся числа проверяем на оставшиеся простые числа.

Comment: Идея неплоха,я пробовал строить решето Эратосфена,но получал memory limit,не знаю уложусь ли я теперь в секунду,если буду использовать вашу идею,но такое я еще не рассматривал